# passport js vs firebase authentication system

Tags: reactjs, express, firebase-authentication, passport.js

Is there any valid reason to use passport js based authentication using express js in backend over firebase authentication system in frontend using react?

just explored passport js and want to know before using in a MERN Stack project

Answer (score 2):

PassportJS is just an authentication middleware that can be used with different [authentication strategies](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/). If I understood you correctly you might be comparing Passport's local strategy with Firebase auth's username/password one, in this case:

My answer would be a classical "[IT DEPENDS](https://convincedcoder.com/2018/08/31/It-depends/)", first I will answer the first part:

#### Why use Firebase-auth (or any other third-party authentication service)

> Authentication is hard, and you may not want to deal with it on your own (most of the time).

If you are planning to use a "local" authentication strategy with a username/email and a password, you might need to consider and maintain a set of best practices to avoid having a [broken-authentication](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A2_2017-Broken_Authentication) system, you will need to encrypt your passwords and ensure that they're safe on at-rest and in-transit, you also want to ensure that your system uses libraries or logic to avoid [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack). Also, you may need to consider forcing some rules on password lengths and that they're not too weak (ex: they belong to a list of most-known passwords)...

Besides these, you may also want to implement password recovery mechanisms, email change, and maybe "Email confirmation" logic which might be tricky sometimes.
Did I forget to mention reCaptcha and 2FA? Bots are getting smarter nowdays.

I definitely missed some other best practices or risks that should be considered when not using a managed service like Firebase-auth.

These services are built by people who only care about "Authentication" for you.

Firebase-auth is not the only service, you may want to look into other options like [auth0](https://auth0.com/).

Of course, this option is not the cheapest in terms of cost and flexibility. Firebase auth has a generous free tier, but it will be paid when your application grows, see: https://firebase.google.com/pricing.

So, if you go with this option, consider organizing your application code to be easily decoupled from Firebase in case you wanted to migrate from it someday.

#### Why use Passport-local

Using the middleware on your own means that you will have more flexibility in managing your different authentication strategies and you will only pay an extra cost of maintaining your application's authentication logic (which might be high as you need to keep in mind the best practices and risks)

#### Other considerations

This depends on your use case, and your team:

- You may look into some services that handle the authentication out of the box like Keycloak
- Use Passport.js as a core library but with strategies like Auth0's (https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-auth0/)

Comment: Thank you @Fcmam5 for detailed explanation. Regarding this I have one situation. We have our REST API server and we are developing one application in React. Right now I am using Passport.js with passport-google-oidc strategy. Certainly Firebase authentication would be more secure. Now if we go with firebase authentication in App, how to create session on server to protect REST APIs.

Comment: @Gagan I don't know what you mean by Firebase-auth is more secure, but you might be looking for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#node.js Just pass the token as a header and read it from the backend, then verify it using firebase admin sdk

Comment: @Fcmama5 that;s what I was looking for. This would help me a lot. Thank you.